# Does SQL Server support hash indexes?

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes

Are all the indexes in SQL Server B Tree?
Surely primary keys and foreign should be hash based indexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all indexes in SQL Server are B-tree indexes (SQL Server 2012 added [columnstore indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx) which are a bit different), but there is no such thing as a hash-based index there (yet).

Comment: thanks. Just wondering is this not a major advantage the like of Oracle and MySql have over Sql Server as surely primary keys and foreign keys should be hashed based.  If you have a link to article that would be great. I can't find one.

Comment: Maybe, but implementation of a major feature is not simply a matter of "some other RDBMS has it"...

Comment: Hash indexes will be available in SQL Server 2014

Comment: @MikkaRin only on memory-optimized tables. And if you think you will just be able to make all your tables memory-optimized and call it a day, you need to do some more research.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty straight forward article explaining that all indices are b tree indices in SQL Server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443(v=sql.105).aspx

I think if you want to get more into the nitty gritty of specific RDBMS' implementations, you could try posting to http://dba.stackexchange.com