# SQL Server : where clause performance theory?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If `TableA` has 1,000,000 billion rows (although it is impossible in a true environment) and the primary key increased by identity, so the max row is 1 million billion. Now I used a `Random()` number to match it's where statement. Like below:

```
Select * 
from TableA a 
where a.PrimaryKey = [Random Number from 1 to 1 million Billion]
```

If the `Select` statement executes 100 times, but I found it is still very fast in SQL Server.

I mean if random number is a big number, then if `Select * from Table where Pk=1000000`, it must be comparing with the all previous records to see if THIS number whether match the primary key column. So the performance of SQL will be very low.

Comment: If you have an index you wouldn't be comparing it to all records, just look it up from the index

Comment: You are searching an index. It is a tree and time complexity of binary search is O(logN). It doesnt verifies all prev rows. When you are searching in phonebook for particular number you are not checking all prev pages right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fast because the primary key is indexed, which means the lookup of a row based on the primary key takes O(log N) time ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation ) if you're using a B-tree based index, which is the default in most database systems.

It's further helped by the fact the primary-key is usually the clustered-index too, which is the index that defines the physical order of rows on disk (this is a gross over-simplification, but you get the idea).

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri A hash-based index can be used for O(1) lookup time provided the user is not performing range-based or order-by queries. I think by default it uses a B-tree, but one can easily opt-in to using a hash-based index.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Not SQL Server yet, apparently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890929/does-sql-server-support-hash-indexes

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I've revised my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The primary key is a *key*. That is the database maintains a unique index on the location of every record by the key value.

The index is usually some variation on b-tree which would probably have a depth of about 10 to 20 for such a large dataset. So accessing any record via the key would involve a maximum of 10 IOs and probably much less as large parts of the B-Tree will be cached in memory.